# empty return ansible query

Tags: json, ansible

I have a json named `list_new_job_templates`.

```
- name: "Info list_new_job_templates"
  debug:
    msg: "{{list_new_job_templates}}"
```

returns:

```
    {
        "msg": [
            {
                "name_job_template": "JT_syssec_check_connectivity",
                "id_job_template": 2705,
                "id_job_template_new": 3624
            },
            {
                "name_job_template": "JT_syssec_custom_linux",
                "id_job_template": 2982,
                "id_job_template_new": 3625
            },
            {
                "name_job_template": "JT_syssec_custom_linux_async_p1",
                "id_job_template": 3583,
                "id_job_template_new": 3626
            },
            {
                "name_job_template": "JT_syssec_custom_linux_async_p2",
                "id_job_template": 3593,
                "id_job_template_new": 3627
            }
        ],
        "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
        "_ansible_no_log": false,
        "changed": false
    }
```

I do a query on it to check whether there is a position with a certain `id_job_template` like this:

```
- name: Check 4
  debug:
    msg: "{{ list_new_job_templates|json_query('[?id_job_template==specific_node.id]') }}"
```

The message returned is `[]`

```
- name: Check specific_node.id
  debug:
    msg: "{{ specific_node.id }}"

{
    "msg": "2705",
    "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "changed": false
}
```

I am expecting to receive:

```
{
    "name_job_template": "JT_syssec_check_connectivity",
    "id_job_template": 2705,
    "id_job_template_new": 3624
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `selectattr()` filter.

```yaml
- name: Check 4
  debug:
    msg: "{{ list_new_job_templates | selectattr('id_job_template', 'equalto', specific_node.id) }}"
```

This should return a list of elements that have the attribute `id_job_template` *equalto* `specific_node.id`.

The output of the above:

```
TASK [Check 4] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "id_job_template": 2705,
            "id_job_template_new": 3624,
            "name_job_template": "JT_syssec_check_connectivity"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that this is a **list**, so if you need to (and assuming the result is not an empty list), you can use `| first` filter to get the first element.